# React Redux getting NaN after mapping state

Tags: reactjs, redux, mapping, state, redux-form

I'm having an issue with mapping over my state. My state contains an array of objects, each with two key:value pairs:

```
[
 {
  name: '',
  weight: 0
 }
]
```

My issue is with accessing the values of weight. When I only have one object there is no issue with mapping, I get the value of weight as a number. But when I add a second object to the state and I map over the value of weight in both objects, I get NaN.
The results of the map are going into a percentage calculator, thats why I need the numbers.
Here is a screenshot of my app where I only have one object:
[image]
Here is a screenshot where I have two objects. I am also calling mapWeights in the 'One Rep Max' section at the top, so it shows both '300' and '400'. I plan on fixing this. But this is where I start to get NaN:
[image]
Here is how I am calling .map:

```
    const mapWeights = props.weight.map(value => parseInt(value.movementWeight));
```

Here is where I am calling the mapped result:

```
  useEffect(() => {
        const arr = [];
        let percentage = 100;
        while (percentage > 50 ) {
            arr.push([percentage, (mapWeights * percentage) / 100]);
            percentage -= 5;
        }
        setResults(arr);
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, []);
```

In case you need my reducer:

```
const addMovementReducer = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_MOVEMENT: 
            return [ ...state, action.payload ];
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `mapWeights` is an array, so what would be the value of multiplying an array by a number? `NaN` seems about right. What are you expecting the result of the `useEffect` to be?

Comment: @DrewReese my goal is to add each number in the array to the useEffect and get the percentage breakdown of that number. I guess this might not be the best way to go about it though.

Comment: "my goal is to add each number in the array to the useEffect and get the percentage breakdown of that number." Can you clarify which array and number you are referring to, and also what your expected result should be (*an example result array/object*)?

Comment: @DrewReese I updated my question to include screenshots of where the result will go (in the chart under 'weight'). So in my app the user adds a name and weight through a form, and those go into my state array as an object. When they click submit, a button is created with the name that they submitted. When they click that button they get to the page that I have screenshots of above. What I'm trying to do is show the weight of whichever exercise they clicked on. So if they click on 'Bench' it should show the percentages of '300'. If they click on 'Squat' it should show '400' and so on.

Comment: I don't see any added screenshots or edits to your post, but I'm gathering that you likely want to process the movement (the array of objects with `name` and `weight`) array and for each weight generate an array of percentages. Is this correct and what you mean by "So if they click on 'Bench' it should show the percentages of '300'"?

Comment: @DrewReese Yes, that is correct. Thank you for putting that into words, I was struggling to explain myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a function that takes *a specific* weight value and maps an array of percent values to an array of percentages for that weight.

```
const percentValues = [100, 95, 90, 85, 80, 75, 70, 65, 60, 55];

const computePercentages = (weight) =>
  percentValues.map((percent) => (weight * percent) / 100);
```

Then use the `computePercentages` utility where you want to compute these arrays of percentages.

```
const data = [
  {
    name: "Bench",
    weight: 300
  },
  {
    name: "Squat",
    weight: 400
  }
];

const percentages = data.map((el) => {
  return computePercentages(el.weight);
});
```

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: "Bench",
    weight: 300
  },
  {
    name: "Squat",
    weight: 400
  }
];

const percentValues = [100, 95, 90, 85, 80, 75, 70, 65, 60, 55];

const computePercentages = (weight) =>
  percentValues.map((percent) => (weight * percent) / 100);

const percentages = data.map((el) => {
  return computePercentages(el.weight);
});

console.log(percentages);
```

In React it is probably more likely that you want to map the original data along with the derived data. For this you can "merge" the data into a single array that is easy to map over to JSX.

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: "Bench",
    weight: 300
  },
  {
    name: "Squat",
    weight: 400
  }
];

const percentValues = [100, 95, 90, 85, 80, 75, 70, 65, 60, 55];

const computePercentages = (weight) =>
  percentValues.map((percent) => (weight * percent) / 100);

const dataWithPercentages = data.map((el) => {
  return {
    ...el,
    percentages: computePercentages(el.weight),
  };
});

console.log(dataWithPercentages);
```